# Integrating a function inside a root power

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, substitution

I am trying to integrate a function -

$\int_0^1 \int_y^1 {(x^r+y^r) }^{1/r}\,dx\,dy$

Here, r lies in [0,1]

I tried to solve it using substitution but to no avail. How can I solve it?

Here's what I have tried so far -

Taken u = $x^r+y^r$  and v=y

Solving for x gives -

x= ${(u-v^r)}^{1/r}$

Jacobian function for the above is - ${{(1/r)}(u-v^r)}^{{1/r}-1}$

So, the Integration function becomes -

${{(1/r)}(u-v^r)}^{{1/r}-1}{u^{1/r}}$ which is not any easier to solve.

I have tried various substitutions
like

u=$x^r+y^r$ ;
v=$x^r-y^r$

u=$x/y$;  v= $xy$

I can share all these results too but they are generating very complex equations as well.

I don't want the solution. If anyone can point out my mistake and give some hint on how to proceed, I'll be deeply grateful.

PS: This is not a homework question.

Also, I used desmos to see whether solution exist by plugging random values of r and it existed for all r in (0,1].

Please direct me.

Comment: This doesn’t have a simple answer for arbitrary r. For some special r, there are nice values. For example, r=2 will get you a multiple of $\pi$ and r=1 is easy to calculate.

Comment: But for this problem r is between 0 and 1. And for this r value of function is defined. Value of function falls as r reaches to 1. Can you suggest how to solve this? Won't substitution be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the most pleasant integral except if you are familiar with hypergeomatric functions.

First,
$$\int\left(x^r+y^r\right)^{\frac{1}{r}}\,dx=x y \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{r},\frac{1}{r};\frac{1+r}{r};-\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^r\right)$$ where appears the gaussian hypergeometric function. So, the inner definite integral is
$$I(y)=\int_y^1\left(x^r+y^r\right)^{\frac{1}{r}}\,dx=$$$$y \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{r},\frac{1}{r};\frac{1+r}{r};-y^{-r}\right)-y^2 \,
   _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{r},\frac{1}{r};\frac{1+r}{r};-1\right)$$ Now, start complicated stuff; a CAS gives the antiderivative (too long to be printed here) but the definite integral is
$$\frac{1}{6} \left(\,
   _2F_1\left(-\frac{2}{r},-\frac{1}{r};\frac{r-2}{r};-1\right)-\frac{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{r}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{r-2}{r}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(-\frac{1}{r}\right)}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer was truly helpful.